# How to insert coordinates of a table into an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, html-table, coordinates, cells

I am making the game battleships in PHP and I need to make it so that the computer randomly chooses 5 coordinates(x, y), and they have to be in a straight line (column or row). How do I make it so the coordinates are in a line and how do I connect the coordinates to the table cells?

Here's what I have so far:

```
<?php

session_start();


$i=0;
$start=1;
$st=65;
$l=0;
$polje=array();
$x=(mt_rand(0, 10));
$y=(mt_rand(0, 10));

for($q=0; $q<5; $q++){
$polje[$l]=array($x, $y);
}


echo "<table id='table'>\n";


while ($i<11){
    $ascii=chr($st);
    echo "<tr>";
    for($k=0; $k<11; $k++, $start++){
        if($k==0){
            echo "<td>$i</td>";
        }
        else if($i==0){
            echo "<td class='td2'>$ascii</td>";
            $ascii++;
        }
        else{
            echo "<td class='td1'> </td>";
        }

    }
    echo "</tr>";
    $i++;
}




?>
```

This is what the table looks like:

[image: table]

Comment: This is really a mathematical question. This should help: http://thevirtuosi.blogspot.com/2011/10/linear-theory-of-battleship.html

Comment: Don't choose 5 randoms positions choose one for bow and then a random direction.

Comment: Not just the mathematic one, I also don't know how to connect the random coordinates and the table cells

Comment: I think you need to do a bit more research. You are asking us to do a lot for you here.

Comment: I just want to know what is the best method to connect the table cells with these coordinates, don't need for anyone to actually write out the whole source code, I just have no idea how to connect these elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like this kind of challenge.
Of course, there is a lot of ways, better ways to do this, with OOP, but you can get the point.
Read the comments through the code and if you have any doubts feel free to ask.
I did some treatment to avoid ships overlapping each other, and random deployment.

```
const BOARD_SIZE = 10; //10x10 board
const SUBMARINE = 1;
const DESTROYER = 2;
const BATTLESHIP = 3;
const AIRCRAFTCARRIER = 4;

$ships_available = [];
//populate with some data based on game rule
array_push($ships_available, SUBMARINE);
array_push($ships_available, SUBMARINE);
array_push($ships_available, DESTROYER);
array_push($ships_available, DESTROYER);
array_push($ships_available, DESTROYER);
array_push($ships_available, BATTLESHIP);
array_push($ships_available, BATTLESHIP);
array_push($ships_available, AIRCRAFTCARRIER);

$board = [];

while(count($ships_available) > 0) {
    deployShip($board, $ships_available);
}

$lastColumnLetter = chr(ord('A')+ BOARD_SIZE-1);

//print table
echo "<table border='1' align='center'>";
echo "<tr><td></td><td>".implode('</td><td>',range(1, BOARD_SIZE))."</td></tr>";
for($i = 'A'; $i <= $lastColumnLetter; $i++) {
    echo "<tr><td>".$i."</td>";
    for($j=0; $j < BOARD_SIZE; $j++) {
        echo "<td align='center'>";
        echo $board[$i][$j] ?: '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
        echo "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
exit;

function array_merge_custom($array1, $array2) {
    foreach($array2 as $key => $value) {
        foreach($value as $k => $v) {
            $array1[$key][$k] = $v;
        }
    }
    return $array1;
}

function deployShip(&$board, &$ships_available) {
    $randomShipKey = array_rand($ships_available);
    $ship = $ships_available[$randomShipKey];
    $beginCoordinates = getRandomCoordinates();
    $coordinates = getShipCoordinates($board, $beginCoordinates, $ship);

    if(!$coordinates) {
        return false;
    }

    unset($ships_available[$randomShipKey]);
    $board = array_merge_custom($board,$coordinates);
}

function getRowNumberByLetter($letter) {
    return array_search($letter, range('A','Z'));
}

function getRowLetterByNumber($number) {
    $letters = range('A','Z');
    return $letters[$number];
}

function getRandomCoordinates() {
    return ['row' => chr(mt_rand(ord('A'), (ord('A') + BOARD_SIZE-1))), 'col' => mt_rand(0,BOARD_SIZE -1)];
}

function getShipCoordinates($board, $beginCoordinates, $ship) {
    if(isset($board[$beginCoordinates['row']][$beginCoordinates['col']])) {
        return false; //anchor position already taken
    }
    if($ship == 1) {
        $return[$beginCoordinates['row']][$beginCoordinates['col']] = 1;
        return $return;
    }

    $shipArraySize = $ship -1;
    $directions = ['left', 'right', 'up', 'down'];
    $tries = 10;
    while($tries > 0) {
        $tries--;
        $direction = $directions[array_rand($directions)];
        $return = [];
        switch($direction) {
            case 'left':
                if(($beginCoordinates['col'] - $shipArraySize) < 0) { //check if can go left
                    break;
                }
                for($colBegin = ($beginCoordinates['col'] - $shipArraySize), $colEnd = $beginCoordinates['col']; $colBegin <= $colEnd; $colBegin++) {
                    if(!empty($board[$beginCoordinates['row']][$colBegin])) {
                        break 2;
                    } else {
                        $return[$beginCoordinates['row']][$colBegin] = $ship;
                    }
                }
                return $return;
            case 'right':
                if(($beginCoordinates['col'] + $shipArraySize) > BOARD_SIZE -1) { //check if can go right
                    break;
                }
                for($colBegin = $beginCoordinates['col'], $colEnd = ($beginCoordinates['col'] + $shipArraySize); $colBegin <= $colEnd; $colBegin++) {
                    if(!empty($board[$beginCoordinates['row']][$colEnd])) {
                        break 2;
                    } else {
                        $return[$beginCoordinates['row']][$colBegin] = $ship;
                    }
                }
                return $return;
            case 'up':
                if((getRowNumberByLetter($beginCoordinates['row']) - $shipArraySize) < 0) { //check if can go up
                    break;
                }
                for($rowBegin = (getRowNumberByLetter($beginCoordinates['row']) - $shipArraySize), $rowEnd = getRowNumberByLetter($beginCoordinates['row']); $rowBegin <= $rowEnd; $rowBegin++) {
                    if(!empty($board[getRowLetterByNumber($rowBegin)][$beginCoordinates['col']])) {
                        break 2;
                    } else {
                        $return[getRowLetterByNumber($rowBegin)][$beginCoordinates['col']] = $ship;
                    }
                }
                return $return;
            case 'down':
                if((getRowNumberByLetter($beginCoordinates['row']) + $shipArraySize) > BOARD_SIZE -1) { //check if can go down
                    break;
                }
                for($rowBegin = getRowNumberByLetter($beginCoordinates['row']), $rowEnd = (getRowNumberByLetter($beginCoordinates['row']) + $shipArraySize); $rowBegin <= $rowEnd; $rowBegin++) {
                    if(!empty($board[getRowLetterByNumber($rowBegin)][$beginCoordinates['col']])) {
                        break 2;
                    } else {
                        $return[getRowLetterByNumber($rowBegin)][$beginCoordinates['col']] = $ship;
                    }
                }
                return $return;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: You are a genius my friend. Thank you